# Getting unwanted values in a new column with pandas append in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to make a script that loops through rows in dataframe  and makes a new column from appending values from column A or B based on a condition in column C. However, there seem to be something wrong in the appending of the rows in the columns, as my new column contain several values.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Loading in the csv file
filename = '35180_TRA_data.csv'
df1 = pd.read_csv(filename, sep=',', nrows=1300, skiprows=25, index_col=False, header=0)

#Calculating the B concentration using column A and a factor
B_calc = df1['A']*137.818

#The measured B concentration
B_measured = df1['B']

#Looping through the dataset, and append the B_calc values where the C column is 2, while appending the B_measured values where the C column is 1.
calculations = []

for row in df1['C']:
    if row == 2:
        calculations.append(B_calc)
    if row ==1:
        calculations.append(B_measured)

df1['B_new'] = calculations
```

The values of my new column (B_new) are all wrong. For example in the first row it should be just 0.00, but it contains numerous values. So something is going wrong in the appending. Anyone who can spot that problem?

Comment: Looks like your `calculations` is an array of Series since each time you append a series to it. You should avoid looping rows if possible. Instead, use Boolean masking or `np.where`.

Comment: @QuangHoang: Thanks! I used np.where and that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

B_calc and B_measured are arrays. As such you have to specify which value you want to assign, otherwise you assign the whole array. Here is how you could do it :

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,3,5,7,9], "B" : [9,7,5,3,1], "C":[1,2,1,2,1]})
#Calculating the B concentration using column A and a factor
B_calc = df1['A']*137.818

#The measured B concentration
B_measured = df1['B']
#Looping through the dataset, and append the B_calc values where the C column is 2, while appending the B_measured values where the C column is 1.
calculations = []

for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['C'] == 2:
        calculations.append(B_calc[index])
    if row['C'] ==1:
        calculations.append(B_measured[index])

df1['B_new'] = calculations
```

---

But it's a bad practice to iterate on rows because it takes a long time. A better way is to use pandas masks, here is how it works :

```
mask_1 = df1['C'] == 1
mask_2 = df1['C'] == 2

df1.loc[mask_1, 'C'] = df1[mask_1]['A']*137.818
df1.loc[mask_2, 'C'] = df1[mask_2]['B']
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions! I used np.where as suggested in a comment above which solved my problem.